# EXISTS query in Elasticsearch and Spring Data

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data

I need to find all the documents in type `invoice` where field `rate` exists. I have this code:

```
public interface MyRepo extends ElasticsearchRepository<Invoice, String> {

    List<Invoice> findByRateExists();

}
```

but I'm getting an error:

> Illegal criteria found 'EXISTS (0): [Exists]'.

Same error if I use `isNUll` operator:

```
List<Invoice> findByRateIsNull();
```

> Illegal criteria found 'IS_NULL (0): [IsNull, Null]'.

`rate` field is an object, not a primitive type.

How can I solve this?

Comment: is this findByrRateExists   a typo ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Edited.

Comment: can you paste a sample document